# Can't get processID using ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I'm trying to get a proccessId using ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId, but the print does not match the PID seen in the task manager. Here is the code

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import windll
import time

time.sleep(2)
hwnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
pid = ctypes.c_ulong()
GetWindowThreadProcessId =ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,pid)
print GetWindowThreadProcessId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 'byref' to the second parameter, like this:

```
lpdw_process_id = ctypes.c_ulong()
result = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(h_wnd, ctypes.byref(lpdw_process_id))
process_id = lpdw_process_id.value
```